# Getting an UnboundLocalError because the 'actual' variable is not always assigned a value

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting an UnboundLocalError, which seems to be related to the fact that the actual variable is not assigned a value. I am using TKInter to create the widget, button, and GUI.
This is the current code so far:

```
 def calculate_accuracy():
     actual_or_forecast = actual_or_forecast_combo_box_button.get()
     actual_or_forecast_data = actual_or_forecast_button_entry.get()
     if actual_or_forecast == 'Actual':
    actual = float(actual_or_forecast_data)
else:
    forecast = float(actual_or_forecast_data)
accuracy = (forecast - actual) / actual
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation and add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: You seem to know the problem, so it's not clear what kind of help you need. Why do you think you should be able to use `actual` without defining it?

Comment: Eithet `actual` or `forecast` will be defined, not both. So the last line will raise exception.

Comment: I see. I just knew that. So how do we define both? To calculate the accuracy?

Comment: Use two entry boxes to input the *actual* and *forecast* values.

Comment: I want to ask for clarification because even if I use two entry foxes, I can't get it to a number input. How do I do this?

Comment: You have already know how to convert the input to float number using `float(...)`, so I don't understand why you have the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you've defined the actual and forecast variables inside an if statement but there's a possibility that neither of them will be defined if the condition is not met.
you should define actual and forecast outside of the if statement and initialize them to None or something else that you think :

```
    def calculate_accuracy():
        actual = None
        forecast = None

        actual_or_forecast = actual_or_forecast_combo_box_button.get()
        actual_or_forecast_data = actual_or_forecast_button_entry.get()
        if actual_or_forecast == 'Actual':
            actual = float(actual_or_forecast_data):
        else:
            forecast = float(actual_or_forecast_data)
```

In this case, you can add a condition and check that the actual and forecast values ​​are not None.